# Asp.net Ajax no return after Sql query

Tags: asp.net

I'm a very beginner with Asp.net , now I have make a programming as below , With a ajax , it successfully returned  with "Hello GC"

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectList() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "default.aspx/GetSelectList",
            data: '{name:"GC"}',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d );
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });
    }
   </script>
```

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetSelectList(ByVal name As String) As String

    Dim Result_str As String = "Hello " & name
    Return Result_str 
    
End Function
```

but When I add the Sql query function , the SQL function  is ok (***MsgBox(dsTable.Rows(0)("Name"))*** indicate the query is ok ) ,but there is no return "Hello GC" any more , as  below :
I don't know why ,all seems normal

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetSelectList(ByVal name As String) As String

    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(MysqlconStr)
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
    conn.Open()

    Dim SQL_str As String = $“SELECT * FROM `selectlist` WHERE TYPE_id='{name}'”
    Dim dsTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim daAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL_str, conn)

    daAdapter.Fill(dsTable)

    'MsgBox(dsTable.Rows(0)("Name"))

    Dim Result_str As String = "Hello " & name
    Return Result_str 
       End Function
```

Comment: did you get any problem or what output now you are getting?